# Problemas al capturar los datos enviados desde una pagina a una api

Tags: php, api

Hola acudo nuevamente a vosotros porque tengo una duda, estoy intentado integrar la API de mensatek en php y no logro capturar los datos correctamente.

¿alguien puede echarme una mano?.

mi codigo es el siguiente:

**1- formulario php**

```
<form action="envio-sms" method="post">
  <div class="card-body" >

 <div class="form-body">

<div class="row p-t-20">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Remitente"><strong>Remitente</strong></label>
<div class="input-group">
<input name="Remitente" id="Remitente" type="text"  class="form-control" >
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Destinatarios"><strong>Destinatario</strong></label>
<div class="input-group">
<input name="Destinatarios" id="Destinatarios" type="text"  class="form-control" >
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Mensaje"><strong>Mensaje</strong></label>
<div class="input-group">
<input name="Mensaje" id="Mensaje" type="text"  class="form-control" >
</div>
</div>
</div>


<CENTER><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="ti-email"></i> Enviar SMS </button><CENTER>
</form>
```

**Api Mensatek:**

```
<?php
require_once("mensatek.inc");
// Crear instancia Clase
$Mensatek=new cMensatek("mimail.com","micontraseña");
$variables=array(
"Remitente"=>"MI EMpresa",  //Remitente que aparece, puede ser número de móvil, fijo (formato internacional +346XXXXXXX) o texto (hasta 11 caracteres)

"Destinatarios"=>"3466XXXXXXX", // Destinatarios del mensaje, si es más de 1 sepárelos por punto y coma

"Mensaje"=>"Su mensaje de prueba.", //Mensaje, si se envían más de 160 caracteres se enviará en varios mensajes

"Report"=>0,  //Report de entrega al correo electrónico por defecto
"Descuento"=>0,  // Si utiliza descuento o no. Descuento=0 es sin descuento. Descuento=2 añadirá (MENSATEK.ES) al final del mensaje, Descuento=1 pondrá MENSATEK.ES como remitente
"Fecha"=>"2015-09-30 10:20" //Si quiere programar el envío
);


// Ejemplo de envío
$res=$Mensatek->enviar($variables);
if ($res["Res"]>0)
{
    echo "<br/>Se enviaron ".$res["Res"]." mensajes y le restan ".$res["Cred"]." cr&eacute;ditos (se han utilizado ".$res["CreditosUsados"]." cr&eacute;ditos";
    echo "<br/>El resultado completo es:<pre>".print_r($res,true)."</pre>";

// Ejemplo de obtendión directa de créditos restantes en su cuenta
    echo "<br>Le restan ".$Mensatek->Creditos." cr&eacute;ditos";
}
else echo "<br>Se ha producido el error ".$res["Res"]." consulte el significado en la documentación de la API";




?>
```

Alguna idea de como puedo capturar los datos en la API??

Comment: Podes aclarar si es que recibis un error, si los datos llegan, no llegan, algo por donde empezar a ayudarte?

Comment: Error-5 Tipo de Contenido no admitido o no existe uno de los archivox- este es el error que me escupe

Comment: usa el boton [edit], aclara tu error y todo lo que recibis en la pregunta.

Comment: Quien lo saca ese error, en que momento, hasta donde ejecuta bien.. toda esa información falta

Comment: Lo que me gustaría saber es como capturo los datos del formulario en la API?

Comment: Lo que me gustaría saber es como capturo los datos del formulario en la API?

Comment: aCTUALIZO EL CODIGO